# Inserir itens do Banco de dados no Tbody de uma tabela HTML usando um laço de repetição

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

Bom dia,
Estou fazendo a listagem de produtos de um banco de dados em uma pagina Html + PHP, com o código que desenvolvi,utilizando um While que executa até que a tabela do banco de dados ainda possuir linhas, já consigo pegar as informações do banco e listar na pagina, pulo linha a cada informação e quando muda de item passo um traço na pagina e também fiz a paginação.

Esta listando corretamente, porem por motivos de estética criei uma tabela e em vez de listar os itens na pagina utilizado o "echo" gostaria de adicionar diretamente na tabela.
Não sou conhecedor de JavaScript por isso gostaria de saber se existe um jeito de fazer isso com php e html mesmo.

Obrigado desde já!

Codigo:

```html
<!-- Tabela criada para tentar inserir os dados -->

<body>
  <h1>Lista de Produtos</h1>
  <table class="table table-hover" id="tabres">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Código</td>
        <td>Descrição</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="lsprodutos">
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <?php
$pagina_atual = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'pagina',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$pagina = (!empty($pagina_atual)) ? $pagina_atual : 1; 

$qnt_result_pg = 3;

$inicio = ($qnt_result_pg * $pagina) - $qnt_result_pg;

$sql="select codigo,descricao,valor from loja.produto order by codigo LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg";
$resultado_produtos = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

#Repetiçao que uso para inserir os dados na pagina
#Aqui gostaria de subistituir o echo por algo que insira na tabela que criei la em cima

while($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produtos)){
    echo "Codigo " . $row_produto['codigo'] . "<br>";
    echo "Descricao ". $row_produto['descricao'] . "<br>";
    echo "Valor " . $row_produto['valor'] . "<br><hr>";
}
$result_pg = "SELECT COUNT(codigo) AS num_result FROM produto";
$resultado_pg = mysqli_query($conn,$result_pg);
$row_pg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_pg);

$quantidade_pg = ceil($row_pg['num_result'] / $qnt_result_pg);

$max_links = 2;
echo "<a href='listaproduto.php?pagina=1'>Primeira"
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia.
É possível colocar o `echo` dentro do `tbody` da tabela.
Para isso, coloque o código `PHP` que faz a consulta na tabela loja.produto no início da página. Logo, vamos mesclar o trecho do `while` com a tabela. Dentro de `<tbody id="lsprodutos">` coloque o código abaixo. Deve ficar assim:

```
<?php while($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produtos)){ ?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row_produto['codigo']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_produto['descricao']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_produto['valor']; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Caso prefira, é possível fazer também da maneira que está respondido nessa questão https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902483/show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-on-a-webpage

Comment: Leonardo muitíssimo grato pela atenção, seu código resolveu meu problema.